# Are multiple column index used in single column where clause

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql

I have a table with a defined non clustered index on 3 columns.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MyIndex] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Col1] ASC,
    [Col2] ASC,
    [Col3] ASC
)
```

Will it be used if i do a request with a where clause on a single column or do I need to create a new index on the specified column?

e.g. :
`SELECT TOP 1000 * from MyTable WHERE Col2 in (1,2,3)`

Comment: Does your table have a lot of other columns? In other words, will the SELECT * require a key lookup, or is it really just those three columns plus maybe an identity column?

Answer (score 3):

The index can be SEEKed if you search on Col1 (first column), which implies that it can also be used if you search for Col1 AND Col2.

It can *possibly* be *scanned* if you search for Col2 (i.e. the other column(s)) but *not* Col1. But if it is depends on whether it covers the index, estimated selectivity and stuff like that. And even if it would be used, a scan is never as effective as a seek (rest being equal).

Comment: it isnt always the case that seek is better than scan (usually it is). https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/04/index-scans-arent-always-bad-and-index-seeks-arent-always-great/